# Python immutable types in function calls

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlalchemy query that returns a tuple. I pass this tuple to a function, and since it's an immutable type, a new instance of the tuple is created in the called function.

How does python deal with this in terms of memory management? Is a complete copy of the tuple created, or is it using some clever 'copy on write/zero copy' like functionality?

The problem for me is that these original tuples can consume large amounts of memory, and just by calling a function to do some processing on them, Python will effectively double the memory consumption.

With the exception of writing the code inline, how can I avoid such inefficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, just a reference to the tuple gets passed, not a copy. The fact that it's immutable doesn't mean that it will be copied on a function call, just that you can't modify it.

Comment: Ok, according to: [link] http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/5126 "Some objects, like strings, tuples, and numbers, are immutable.  Altering them inside a function/method will create a new instance and the original instance outside the function/method is not changed." Does this mean a new instance is created only when an attempt to modify the passed tuple/string is made?

Comment: Yup, you pass the reference by value (small), but the object it's referencing (large) isn't being copied.

Answer (score 0):

Python passes references to objects by value. So you dont need to worry about it.