# Python immutable object from within function

Tags: python

I asked a previous question on stackoverflow here: [Python immutable types in function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653150/python-immutable-types-in-function-calls)

which made it clear that only references to immutable objects are passed to functions, and so passing a tuple to a function does *not* result in a full memory copy of that object.

However, according to: http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/5126

> "Some objects, like strings, tuples,
>   and numbers, are immutable. *Altering*
>   them inside a function/method will
>   create a new instance and the original
>   instance outside the function/method
>   is not changed."

I wrote some test code, where an immutable object is passed to a function. As expected, I can modify the object via the parameter-name/reference defined as part of the function header, and all changes only persist within the called function, leaving the original object outside of the function untouched.

So my question is:

Is the new instance created *only when an attempt is made to alter/modify* the object passed in? I'm guessing that if the object is not changed, a reference to it is all that is required. **More importantly, if it does create a copy upon attempted modification, how does python manage the memory? With a zero-copy/copy-on-write, or does it create a complete replicated object (with the whole object's size reserved in memory) visible only within the called function?**

Comment: "...an immutable object is passed to a function. As expected, I can modify the object..." No can do. That's the definition of immutable. Could you show the code? There may be something else going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will think a lot more clearly about variables in Python if you think of them not as boxes that contain values, but names that are attached to objects. Any object can have any number of names attached to it; some of the names are local to functions and will be taken off the object automatically when the function returns.

So when you do something like this:

```
name = "Slartibartfast"
person = name
```

There is a string object, which contains the text "Slartibartfast", and there are two names by which it can be referred: `name` and `person`. You get the same object in both cases; you can verify this with the `id()` function.

Which is the "real" name of the string, `name` or `person`? This is a trick question. The string does not inherently have a name; it is just a string. `name` is not a box that *contains* "Slartibartfast", it is just an identifier that refers to the object. `person` has exactly the same standing in Python; `name` is not "more important" just because it was assigned first.

> NOTE: Some objects, such as functions and classes, have a `__name__` attribute that holds the name that was used to declare it in the `def` or `class` statement. This is the object's "real name" if it can be said to have one. However, you can still reference it through any number of assigned names.

Now, suppose you "modify" the string to give it a bit more of a Dutch flavor:

```
person = person.replace("art", "aart")
```

"Modify" is in quotes because you can't modify a string. Since a string is immutable, *every string operation* creates a new string.  When does it happen? *Immediately.* In this case, the new string "Slaartibaartfast" is created and the name `person` is adjusted to refer to that.  However, the name `name` still refers to the original string, because you haven't told it to refer to anything else. As long as at least one name refers to it, Python will keep good old "Slartibartfast" around.

This is no different when dealing with a function:

```
def dutchnametag(name):
    name = name.replace("art", "aart")
    print "HELLO! My Dutch name is", name

person = "Slartibartfast"
dutchnametag(person)
```

Here we assign the string "Slartibartfast" to the global name `person`. We then pass that string to our function, where it receives the additional local name `name`. The string's `replace()` method is then called through the `name` identifier, creating a new string. The identifier `name` is then reassigned to point to the new string. Outside the function, the global identifier `person` still refers to the original string, because nothing has changed it to point to anything else.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense and helped a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Just curious, where in Python documentation does it say that assignment to immutable objects result in a creation of a new object? (Of course I know it does, just couldn't find it explicitly stated..)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not speaking about python per se. But generally, in immutable data structures, every method that you use that needs to change state will return a new object (with the modified state). The old one will remain the same.

For example, a Java mutable list could have:

```
void addItem(Object item) { ... }
```

the correspondent immutable List would have a method in the lines of

```
List addItem(Object item) { ... }
```

So, there is generally nothing special about immutable data structures. In any language you may create immutable data structures. But some languages make it hard or impossible to create mutable data structures (generally, functional languages).

Some languages may provide pseudo-immutable data structures. They make some special data structures look like immutable to the coder, while indeed they aren't.

Comment: Exactly right. The key here, Chris, is to note that every "modification" operation on an immutable object *requires* you to use an assignment statement to save the resulting value, because the old value is "still there" untouched. So operations on immutable objects *always* look like `mydate = olddate + interval` and *never* look like `mydate = olddate; mydate.add(interval)`.

Comment: Ok, but specific to Python: If I have an object of an immutable type with say 3 integer members, and I pass it to a function which then attempts to modify say one of the integers. Will Python create a whole new object (including memory for all 3 integers), or just maintain the memory for the modified integer?

Comment: @Chris - If a function can can modify it, it is not immutable; so python will just let it get modified. There is nothing special going on. If it can be modified, there is no need for a new object, because it won't be modified anyway.

Comment: @Chris: Suppose you have the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`. Tuples are immutable. You pass that to a function, which tries to replace the second item with 5: `x[1] = 5`. Since the tuple is immutable, you get an error. Python won't let you do it. What you have to do is *slice* the tuples into new smaller tuples, then put them back together with the new value in the middle. For example, `x = x[:1] + (2,) + x[2:]`. This creates a new tuple, which is then assigned back to the original name.

Comment: @kindall, thanks I tried something along these lines, and I get a "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment".

Answer (score 1):

If an object is immutable there is no way to change it.  You could assign a new object to the name formerly associated with the argument object.  To do this you first need to make a new object.  So yes, you would allocate space for a complete new object.