# Semantics of args passed to python threading.Thread __init__

Tags: python, multithreading

What are the semantics of data passed to `threading.Thread.__init__()`? Are they copied over and made local to the thread? Or, do they continue to be shared with the creating thread? The docs say that args is a tuple, so I assume it will be deep copied, but would like to make sure.

Basically, I'd like to dump a buffer periodically to disk, and I plan to pass this buffer as the arg to a saving thread's `__init__`. Can I continue to modifying the buffer in the calling thread without worrying if it will be affected in the saving thread?

Comment: There is nothing about tuples that implies deep-copying.

Comment: The tuple itself is immutable, but that doesn't mean the things it holds are. If you pass a list, and the calling thread modifies the list, the called thread will see the change.

Comment: My error in stating what I meant. As args is a tuple, it is immutable in `Thread.__init__`. Or, maybe, I don't understand why the following works:
 `>>> a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
  >>> t = (a, b, c)
  >>> a = 4
  >>> t
  (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Ok, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653150/python-immutable-types-in-function-calls) seems to indicate that immutable builtin types are copy-on-written. So, I can use buffer if its a string without fear of overwriting in another thread, but not, say, a list.

Comment: Immutable types don't need copy-on-write, because they don't support any notion of "write". Using a string as a buffer will work because it is impossible to modify a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data are generally shared in Python unless you explicitly copy. Dumping a buffer from one thread while modifying it in another is not a safe operation unless the buffer itself has a thread-safe design. You need to synchronise access to the buffer somehow.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I continue to modifying the buffer in the calling thread without worrying if it will be affected in the saving thread?

You can if you use `multiprocessing.Process` instead of `threading.Thread` ... the process get's the data at the time of the Process.start() call via fork -- the data in one process cannot modify the data in another process. Although, to do IPC you will need to use a Queue or a Pipe or use shared objects from the multiprocessing module (Value, Array, etc...).